# Dynamically change 'hamburger' nav depending on BG image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change the colour of my 'hamburger' nav element depending on the colour of the image that it floats on top of.

I'm using Kenneth Cache's neat '[backgroundcheck.js](http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/)' script on my text elements. This works by deleting the color of the image and then applying a class (either `.background--light` or `.background--dark` respectively) but it doesn't seem to work on my hamburger probably for two reasons -

- I'm using pseudo classes (`::before` and `::after`)
- The navigation uses `background-color` but I can't use this in my `.background-light` or `background--dark` elements as it then fills in my other elements which need to have an 'invisible' BG.

My hamburger is set-up as follows -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
     jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
     jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

     var delay = 100;
     $('.linkitem').each(function(i, e) {
       setTimeout(function() {
         $(e).toggleClass('animate');
       }, i * delay);
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: .0;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity .55s;
  -moz-transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity .55s;
  -webkit-transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity .55s;
}
.mobile-nav.active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .85;
  height: 100%;
  transition: height .35s ease-in-out, opacity .55s;
  -moz-transition: height .35s ease-in-out, opacity .55s;
  -webkit-transition: height .35s ease-in-out, opacity .55s;
}

.mobile-link-container {
  visibility: inherit;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-links {
  visibility: inherit;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 5%;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.mobile-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.mobilemenu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  z-index: 1010;
  background: none;
}
.mobilemenu:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.mobilemenu span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000000;
}
.mobilemenu span::before,
.mobilemenu span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000000;
  content: "";
}
.mobilemenu span::before {
  top: -8px;
}
.mobilemenu span::after {
  bottom: -8px;
}
.mobilemenu--htx {
  background-color: none;
}
.mobilemenu--htx span {
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}
.mobilemenu--htx span::before,
.mobilemenu--htx span::after {
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}
.mobilemenu--htx span::before {
  transition-property: top, transform;
}
.mobilemenu--htx span::after {
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}
/* active state, i.e. menu open */

.mobilemenu--htx.is-active {
  background-color: none;
}
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span::before,
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
.animate {
  visibility: inherit;
  transform: scale(2, 2) translateX(-100px);
  animation-name: scalenav;
  animation-duration: .50s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  <div class="mobile-link-container">
    <div class="mobile-links">
      <ul>
        Nav Link 1, Nav link 2, Nav link 3
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="mobilemenu mobilemenu--htx">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

The two classes that `background-check.js` applies to elements are:

```
.background--light {
    color: #000000 !important;
    fill: #000000;
}

.background--dark {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I've tried to use `fill:` on my `.mobilemenu` element and also tried adding `background-color` to the two '--light' and '--dark' classes but that just interferes with all the other elements on my page that I'm also applying them too, and also doesn't seem to affect the `::before` and `::after` menu classes

Is there another option to change the hamburger colors dynamically?

I'm open to rewriting the hamburger and getting rid of the psuedo-classes if that helps - the only stipulation is that it must be pure CSS and I want to keep the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `!important` to rewrite the hamburger, like this:

```
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active {
  background-color: red !important;
}
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: red !important;
}
.mobilemenu--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

It can change the hamburger background color.
https://jsfiddle.net/jp6gpdd7/

Comment: Ideally I want to retain the look I have - i.e. the white when active is fine (as the menu slide-down is always black), but I just want the initial hamburger to be either black or white depending on the lightness/darkness of the background image it floats on.